# Change ASP.NET generated Web Service Client GUI

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I need to know if it is possible to change the interface and behavior of the interface that ASP.NET generates to consume Web Services.

Basically, the generated interface calls the Web Service on a wrong port (I've changed the port on WSDL file), I only want to change the port from 8080 to 80.

If I call the web service from the WSDL file, everything works fine, because the port on the WSDL is 80.

Thanks for your help.
Best Regards,
ukrania

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the port-part of the URL for the webservice:

In code:

```
Public Product As New wsProduct.ProductWs
Product.Url ="http://localhost:80/product.asmx"
```

Same goes if you do it in the designer on the property page for the webservice reference.